# smtp.mail.ru, JavaMailSender, бесконечное ожидание и PKIX path building failed

Tags: java, email, smtp, mail.ru

Пытаюсь отправлять письмо с ящика mail.ru, используя JavaMailSender. Перепробовал различные параметры smtp, но ничего не работает.

Использую такие настройки:

- mail.host=smtp.mail.ru
- mail.port=465
- mail.username=noreply@mail.cm.ru (доп. домен)
- mail.password=password
- mail.from=noreply@mail.cm.ru
- mail.protocol=smtps
- mail.smtp.auth=true

Получаю ошибку
**PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.**

Если вместо mail.protocol=smtps использую mail.protocol=smtp, получаю бесконечное ожидание от сервера и сваливаюсь в таймаут.

Сам mail.ru предлагает эти настройки:

- Сервер исходящей почты (SMTP-сервер) smtp.mail.ru
- Порт IMAP — 993 (протокол шифрования SSL/TLS)
- POP3 — 995 (протокол шифрования SSL/TLS)
- SMTP — 465 (протокол шифрования SSL/TLS)
- Аутентификация   Обычный пароль (без шифрования)
- В настройках почтовой программы необходимо указать, что сервер
  исходящей почты (или сервер SMTP) требует авторизации.

Может вы знаете в чем причина? Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Посмотрите настройки сервера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено. Заработало с такими настройками:

```
mail.smtp.host=smtp.mail.ru
mail.smtp.port=465
mail.smtp.auth=true
mail.smtp.starttls.enabled=false
mail.smtp.ssl.protocols=TLSv1.2
mail.smtp.username=noreply@mail.cm.ru
mail.smtp.password=****
mail.smtp.ssl.enable=true
mail.smtp.ssl.trust=smtp.mail.ru
```

Мейлру также требует параметр from, в котором должна быть почта именно от mail.ru. Иначе отправка невозможна.